# My Ajax code cannot post data from database in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have the following javascript code that takes a text from a text area and passes it over to a controller which then updates the database. The controller then gets the same text from the db using a model and passes it over to the javascript code to be displayed on a given div of the webpage without refreshing the page. The controller just works fine and returns the text after successful update to the db but my problem is, the ajax code does not post the same message on the given div, it returns the alert error. I dont know how to fix this, pliz help me.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {

            $('#submit').click(function() {

                //get input data as a array
                var post_data = {
                    'message': $("#message").val(),
                    '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_token_name(); ?>': '<?php echo $this->security->get_csrf_hash(); ?>'
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>index.php/fb/insertByajax",
                    data: post_data,
                    success: function(response) {
                        debugger;
                        // return success message to the id='result' position
                        $("#result").html(response);
                    },
                  error: function() {alert("oops..."); }
                });

            });

        });
    </script>
```

Comment: error: function(e) { console.log(e) }

Comment: thanks @RonniSkansing, i have edited my code but I don't see anything. I thought it should display the error log...

Comment: are you looking in the developer console (sorry have to ask), also try and console.log the post data before sending

Comment: Press F12 to see browser console in chrome

Comment: I am using mozilla, how do i see the browser console? @HRM,

Comment: Come on you can google that.. CTRL+SHIFT+J if windows

Comment: Thanks for your help, am sorry for asking such a silly thing, let me check on it asap.

Comment: Press f12 for mozilla also. Can you show your controller and model code?

Comment: also see the post_data values, are you sending json from controller?Use error msg liek this to view:     error: function(xhr, status, error) {
  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
  alert(err.Message);
}

Comment: have you try to change the post_data to this? message: $("#message").val(),

Answer (score 0):

First, understand that `base_url()` is different of `site_url()` exactly because the second one appends `/index.php` or `$config['index_page']` value. So you want:

...

`url: "<?php echo site_url('fb/insertByajax'); ?>",`

Also check in network session of Chrome's developer tools if there is any bad response from your page.